# Magento 2.3.1 Product Thumbnail Image is not displaying

Tags: product, product-images, cache, magento2.3.1

After upgrading Magento Website from Version 2.0 to Version 2.3.1, product thumbnails are not displaying in "Most Viewed Products". Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below and see if it helps:

Resize catalog images, it could be that the image sized need to be "calibrated" again `catalog:images:resize`

Reindex the catalog: `indexer:reindex`

Clear & Flush Cache: `cache:flush` &  `cache:clean`

Comment: Thanks. Tried all the commands, but no luck. I tried to debug the code and found $product->getThumbnail() is returning NULL

Comment: @Srinivas Is it a Block/Widget? If so have you tried removing it and re-adding? Also do your images have the thumbnail item assigned to them?

Comment: It is a Widget. All products are having thumbnails assigned.